# implement expand function with racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I can't seem to figure out how to write this function. What I am trying to write is a function `expand` that takes a list `lst` as a parameter of the form `'(a (2 b) (3 c))` and is evaluated to `'(a b b c c c)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like homework, so I'm not giving you a straight answer. Instead, I'll give you some pointers in the right direction. The most useful hint, is that you should split the problem in two procedures, one for processing the "outer" list and the other for generating the repetitions encoded in the inner sublists.

Notice that both procedures are mutually recursive (e.g., they call each other). The `expand` procedure recurs over the list, whereas the `repeat` procedure recurs over the number of repetitions. This is the general structure of the proposed solution, fill-in the blanks:

```
; input:  lst - list to be processed
; output: list in the format requested
(define (expand lst)
  (cond ((null? lst)             ; if the list is null
         '())                    ; then return null
        ((not (pair? (car lst))) ; if the first element of the list is an atom
         (cons <???> <???>))     ; cons the atom and advance the recursion
        (else                    ; if the first element of the list is a list
         <???>)))                ; call `repeat` with the right params


; input: n   - number of repetitions for the first element in the list
;        lst - list, its first element is of the form (number atom)
; output: n repetitions of the atom in the first element of lst
(define (repeat n lst)
  (if (zero? n)          ; if the number of repetitions is zero
      (expand (cdr lst)) ; continue with expand's recursion
      (cons <???>        ; else cons the atom in the first element and
            <???>)))     ; advance the recursion with one less repetition
```

Comment: The repeat function processes a single element in the list: the 1st one. When we called it first in `expand`, we passed along the whole list and the `n` number of times stored in the first element. In the recursive step in `expand`, we `cons` together the symbol (a, b, c, etc.) found in the first element, and then continue with the recursion - decrementing `n` for the next step, until finally it reaches zero and we go back to `expand`.

Comment: The last part is almost right: you're correctly passing the number `n`, but you need to pass along `lst`, not just the first element

Comment: I haven't made myself clear, sorry :(. We're passing _the whole list_, it's just that we're sure that the first element is of the form `'(2 a)`. So no, the first ??? would be `(cadar lst)`

Comment: in `repeat` there are only two <???>, why do you have three? the second one is the recursive call, read again my answer: you do _not_ advance the recursion over the list in repeat, only over `n`. As for the error you're getting, check again that you're correctly calling `repeat` in `expand`.

Comment: great, glad to hear it! my pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

As this was answered three years ago, I don't think that I am helping with homework. Would just like to point out that the two functions really don't `need` to be mutually recursive. As `replicate` is a fairly common function, I would propose:

```
(define (replicate what n)
  (if (zero? n)
      (list)
      (cons what (replicate what (- n 1)))))

(define (my-expand xs)
  (if (empty? xs)
      (list)
      (let ((x (first xs)))
        (if (list? x)
            (let ((the-number (first x))
                  (the-symbol (cadr x)))
              (flatten (cons (replicate the-symbol the-number)
                    (my-expand (rest xs)))))
            (cons x (my-expand (rest xs)))))))
```

Of course it is better to use two lists and perform the flatten at the end, something like this:

```
(define (my-expand xs)
  (define (inner-expander xs ys)
    (if (empty? xs) (flatten (reverse ys))
        (let ((x (first xs)))
        (if (list? x)
            (let ((the-number (first x))
                  (the-symbol (cadr x)))
              (inner-expander (rest xs) (cons (replicate the-symbol the-number) ys)))                    
            (inner-expander (rest xs) (cons x ys))))))
  (inner-expander xs (list)))
```

Comment: `(flatten (cons a r))` is really an overkill - you flatten the whole sequence, including the recursive result that was already flattened. using `(append a r)` instead might be better in that respect.

Comment: yeah I know, was just a quick example to make it clear that the two functions can be decoupled. This code was quickly refactored from version that used a two list tail recursive approach - where flatten was called once at the end.

Comment: `append` is not ideal too as it re-traces the first list that `replicate` has just built. so either we  just go with `(append-map replicate_ xs)` (with `replicate` tweaked to correctly handle the two cases) hoping (or not caring) that [`append-map`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi/srfi-std/srfi-1.html#append-map) is implemented efficiently -- or aim to build the result ourselves, in no more than one pass exactly, by `setcdr!`ing the tail as we grow it.

Comment: this is why ideally I would have just show the tail recursive version that reverses and flattens the list at the end. Added a more efficient version - and yes you probably could be smarter about combining reverse and flatten , but my whole point was that replicate is a common function - and if the language had it built it then it could be used.